# Dont know why my contract is charging etherium but not actually creating the struct object on the blockchain

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, dapps, ethereumjs

i have a function in my contract  `createData`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract GeoSpatialData{

    uint public SpatialDataCount = 0;
    uint listingPrice = 0.025 ether;

    function getListingPrice() public view returns (uint256){
        return listingPrice;
    }
    
    struct GeoData{
        uint id;
        address owner_address;
        string data_name;
        string data_year;
        string data_description;
        string data_img_url;
        
        string data_category;
        string data_published_date;
    }

    GeoData[] public geoDatas;
    

    mapping (uint => GeoData) public geodatas;
    // write function
    function createData(string memory _data_name,address _owner_address,string memory _data_year,string memory  _data_description,string memory _data_image_url,string memory _data_published_date,string memory _data_category,int num ) public{
        SpatialDataCount++;
        
        uint used_id = SpatialDataCount;
        geoDatas.push(GeoData({id: used_id,owner_address:_owner_address,data_name:_data_name,data_year:_data_year,data_description:_data_description,data_img_url:_data_image_url,data_category:_data_category,data_published_date:_data_published_date}));
        
    }
}
```

I am calling this from registration.js

```
const createSpatialData = async(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  // formInput.data_published_date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
  let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString()
  updateFormInput({data_published_date:today})
  const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
  const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
  const signer = provider.getSigner()
  var transer ="0xFA08845F4Bf138449865B961a3d11c382776115d"
  let  contract = new ethers.Contract(transer,GeoSpatialData.abi,signer)
  console.log(contract)
  // var listingPrice = await contract.getListingPrice()
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  updateFormInput({data_id:rand})
  // listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()
  var listingPrice ="25000000000000000"
  // console.log(listingPrice)

  const transaction = await contract.createData(formInput.data_name,formInput.data_owner,formInput.data_year,formInput.data_description,formInput.data_img_url,formInput.data_published_date,formInput.data_category,1,)
  await transaction.wait()
  console.log(transaction)
  // console.log("This is the transaction i am getting",transaction)
};
```

See when i am doing console transaction i get everything fine

[image]

The problem is i am not able to see the created object any reason for this plz help

Comment: Check at line 20, the parameters that you pass to the function in registration.js

Comment: what should be tha parameter then